# Track sms conversation with twilio and there is multiple conversation between two numbers

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am building customer service application and I have integrated Twilio for all SMS operations.

Now when customer request for the service system will generate one ticket and details will be messaged on customer's number.

and then the customer can message to my Twilio number which is service center specific(I mean each service center has been assigned one Twilio number) and service center executive can reply him back so I want to make this SMS conversation.

I can use cookies [twilio SMS conversations](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/07/the-definitive-guide-to-sms-conversation-tracking.html) but it won't work in the case when my application will first message as I can only set cookie when my server is actually acting as a server which will be only in receiving SMS

which is narrated in Application Initiated Conversations section in above article.

and another problem is there can be multiple tickets for single user with particular service center so how to manage it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

SMS is a simple protocol that has no idea of different conversations, simply a chronologically ordered set of messages. There are two ways to get around this.

You can either insist that your user include an ID for the ticket they are referring to so that you can parse it out of the message and associate it to the right conversation.

Alternatively, you can add more than one number per service centre that can be used for different conversations.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: yeah I thought for different number but It ll be overhead so I ask ticketid from user